# How can I include css file in vuejs 2 ?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

Currently, I am learning vue2 and I am stuck. My question is where I can include external CSS in Vuejs2 ?

Please suggest me any solution

Thanks

Comment: Your best bet is at the bottom of your index.

Comment: @Beau you mean just include css in index.html in bottom right .?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using webpack you can just import your stylesheets in your main js config and all your components will get the css.
like this :

```
require('./assets/css/main.css');
```

Comment: youre wellcome ;)